# NodeJS - Callback Not executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

After I execute a function (getAvailableLabs) in this case - I want to either execute a callback or a promise.  I'm not sure which I should be executing however I can't get either to work.

Routes:

```
router.get('/api/content_left', function(req, res, next){
    const Labs = require("../models/Labs.js");

    l = new Labs("Sample Lab", "Sample Description", "Sample Category", "Sample Tech");

    l.getAvailableLabs(function(){
        console.log("We made it here!");
        });
    console.log("This is post resposnse");
```

Labs.js:

```
getAvailableLabs() {
    var d = db.any('select * from labs')
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data[0]);
            return data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error + " - Error in function");
            return error;
    });
}
```

In the above case, it logs "end of available labs" followed by "this is post response".  That's what I would expect with my understanding of callbacks.  However it never executes "We made it here!" and I don't understand why?  My impression is if I place a function within a function - it will be executed as a callback however this does not happen.  Do I need return a specific way to execute a callback?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are mixing callbacks with promises..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `getAvailableLabs` function does not accept a callback parameter. I think it'd be best to stay consistent and use promises:

```
getAvailableLabs() {
    return db.any('select * from labs')
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data[0]);
            return data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error + " - Error in function");
            return error;
    });
}

...

l.getAvailableLabs().then(data => {
    console.log("We made it here!");
});
```

If you'd like to use a callback instead of a promise here's how I'd write `getAvailableLabs`:

```
getAvailableLabs (callback) {
    db.any('select * from labs')
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data[0]);
            if (callback) { callback(null, data); }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error + " - Error in function");
            if (callback) { callback(error); }
    });
}
```

Calling this function:

```
getAvailableLabs((err, data) => console.log("We made it here!");
```

Comment: And in the newest versions, you can pair this with async/await.

Comment: Thank you very much!   If it did accept a callback parameter - would that appear as a function({<code>}) within the context of getAvailableLabs()?

Comment: I'll add to my answer as to how you'd do this with a callback since it's too much code for a comment.

Comment: I can't express how much I appreciate your help!  If I could buy you a beer I would.

Comment: @Andy Gaskell your callback style is invalid, in node.js the first parameter must be `error` or `null`, the second `data`. So the first callback call should be `callback(null, data)`, the second - `callback(err)`.